# Object inherited from an entity object put in DB with cast

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api

I'm a dev with a background in Ruby and Node.js but currently working on a C# API with Entity Framework & SQL Server.

I have an Entity "Fon_Campaign", but I wanted to add some methods to this entity so I added an object "Campaign" which inherits from "Fon_Campaign", and gave to this new object a method `isValid()` which watch values and answers if the object is right or not.

**My API method**

```
[Route("Campaigns")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateCampaigns([FromBody]Campaign campaign)
{
    if (campaign == null)
    {
        ErrorMessage resp = new ErrorMessage();
        resp.error = "Parameters are missing";
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, resp);
    }
    else if (campaign.IsValid())
    {
        Fon_Campaign c = campaign;

        db.Fon_Campaign.Add(c); // Error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code, c is considering like an Campaign value and not Fon_Campaign
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, c);
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage resp = new ErrorMessage();
        // Add some explanation
        resp.error = "New campaign is invalid";
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, resp);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to save the object into my DB I'm notified this object is "Campaign" and I can't put it into the DB because I must put in a `Fon_Campaign`, so the cast didn't work.

**My Model**

```
public class Campaign : Fon_Campaign
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope you can help, or give me some indication for a best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using db first which is why you're not just adding `IsValid` to your class. You'll notice the classes generated by Entity Framework are **partial** classes.

```
public partial class Fon_Campaign
{
    // generated properties
}
```

These classes are overwritten by Entity Framework if you update your model from db, so what you can do is make a new folder (let's say ExtendedEntities) and create another **partial** class yourself with the same namespace and class name as the generated one. Now you can add your "IsValid" method there and it won't be overwritten.

```
public partial class Fon_Campaign
{
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The second one will never get overwritten.